# Spring Boot WebFlux Converter

Tags: spring-boot, spring-webflux

I am trying to migrate my project from the Spring MVC to the Spring WebFlux.
The repository I am currently using is `ReactiveCrudRepository`.
In order to achieve the *post-redirect-get* pattern, which I have used within Spring MVC, I need to rewrite the current converter to work with `ReactiveCrudRepository`.

I was trying to do that with this aproach:

```
@Component
public class ObjByIdConverter implements Converter<String, Obj> {

    @Autowired
    private IObjRepository objRepository;

    @Override
    public Obj convert(String id) {
        return objRepository.findById(id).block();
    }
}
```

When I implement converter in this way, I am getting the following error:
`block()/blockFirst()/blockLast() are blocking, which is not supported in thread reactor-http-xxx`.
When I was using `CrudRepository` instead of `ReactiveCrudRepository` everything was worked fine.

Is there a way to implement converter to work with `ReactiveCrudRepository`?

**~~~ Edit 1 ~~~**

The controller class:

```
@PostMapping
public Mono<String> processOrder(@ModelAttribute("newCar") Car car) {

    webDataBinder.validate();
    BindingResult bindingResult = webDataBinder.getBindingResult();

    if (bindingResult.hasErrors()) {
        return Mono.just("orderForm");
    }

    return this.carRepository.save(car).thenReturn("redirect:/");
}
```

The model class:

```
@Document(collection = "cars")
@ToString
@EqualsAndHashCode
public class Car {
    @Id
    private String id;
    private List<Obj> objs = new ArrayList<>();

    // constructor, getters, setters, ...
}
```

I am using the Thymeleaf view technology.

I have to provide the implementation for `ObjByIdConverter` because I am getting the following error message: `[Failed to convert property value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'java.util.List' for property 'objs'; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot convert value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'com.example.app.model.Obj' for property 'objs[0]': no matching editors or conversion strategy found]`

Answer (score 0):

You should not use `block` in any case in reactive development. If you have `ReactiveRepository` and Spring Webflux, use them together with Mono/Flux from repository to controller to leverage the reactive way of doing.

But I think the main reason why you try to convert the result to a standard type is for the `post-redirect-get pattern`, could you detail this in the spring controller context ?